# Swift UI + Cannot assign value of type 'JsonResponse' to type 'JsonResponse.Type'

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below is the code : Getting error : Cannot assign value of type 'JsonResponse' to type 'JsonResponse.Type'
Not sure why it is showing this error.
Any help please

```
struct JsonResponse: Codable {
    var message: String
    var statusCode: String
    var results: Results
}


    class ReadData: ObservableObject  {
        @Published var response = [Results]()
        @Published var message: String = ""
        @Published var jsonData = JsonResponse.self
    
        init(){
            self.loadData()
        }
        
        func loadData()  {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "list", withExtension: "json")
                else {
                    print("Json file not found")
                    return
                }
            
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            if let data = data {
                            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JsonResponse.self, from: data) as JsonResponse {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.message = decodedResponse.message
                                    self.jsonData = decodedResponse // Cannot assign value of type 'JsonResponse' to type 'JsonResponse.Type'
                                }
                                return
                            }
                        }
        }
         
    }
```

Comment: it's at the `@Published var jsonData = JsonResponse.self` - this is relating to the Type itself. You probably want something else there. – replace with `@Published var jsonData: JsonResponse?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
@Published var jsonData:JsonResponse?
```